# Unexpected behavior using Enum.map - only accepts anonymous function

Tags: elixir

I have a `List` of `Tuples`:

```
golden = [{%{"age" => 80, "name" => "Dorothy"}, 
           %{"age" => 50, "name" => "Rose"}},
          {%{"age" => 90, "name" => "Sophia"},
           %{"age" => 60, "name" => "Blanche"}}]
```

**Approach #1**

I use `Enum.map` as follows, but get an error:

```
Enum.map(golden, Tuple.to_list)

** (UndefinedFunctionError) undefined function Tuple.to_list/0
(elixir) Tuple.to_list()
```

**Approach #2**

When I define an anonymous function:

```
f = fn(data) -> Tuple.to_list(data) end
```

And use `Enum.map` with it, I get the desired result:

```
Enum.map(golden, f)

[[%{"age" => 80, "name" => "Dorothy"}, %{"age" => 50, "name" => "Rose"}],
 [%{"age" => 90, "name" => "Sophia"}, %{"age" => 60, "name" => "Blanche"}]]
```

***Maybe I am missing something, but aren't these 2 approaches the exact same thing?***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing `& operator` [Capture operator](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#&/1):

> Captures or creates an anonymous function.

```
iex()> Enum.map(golden, &Tuple.to_list/1)
[[%{"age" => 80, "name" => "Dorothy"}, %{"age" => 50, "name" => "Rose"}],
 [%{"age" => 90, "name" => "Sophia"}, %{"age" => 60, "name" => "Blanche"}]]
```